# Remove the fRecurrence field from the built in Event

Tags: development, calendar

I've made a custom Event type and am trying to figure out how to remove the Recurrence field from the build in SharePoint Event.

Here's my code, which doesn't seem to work :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <!-- Parent ContentType: Event (0x0102) -->
 <ContentType ID="0x0102003841e0a1067b4db29c0baa86c7301e96"
           Name="CountDownEvent15"
           Group="Custom Content Types"
           Description="My Content Type"
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="0"
           >
<FieldRefs>
  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{F2E63656-135E-4f1c-8FC2-CCBE74071901}" Name="fRecurrence" />
</FieldRefs>
```

Does anybody know how I might be able to remove the built in Recurrence field when creating a custom event?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:

1. You can't remove the Recurrence using the elements.xml - at least not this way.
2. You can however remove it using the code below:

   ```
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://MySharePointSite"))
      {
          using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
              SPContentTypeCollection cts = web.ContentTypes;
              SPContentType ct = cts["MyContentType"];
              ct.FieldLinks.Delete("fRecurrence");
              ct.Update(true);
          }
      }
   ```
3. I'm going to change this code and place it in the FeatureActivate method.